# Change app window size from manifest file

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest, galaxy-tab

I want to test an app on a smallscreen device but all I have is a Samsung Galaxy tab. So I thought adding

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"></supports-screens>
```

to the manifest will decrease the window size. But it doesnt work! I even tried setting support for large and normal screens to false but in vain. So I had to change the app's window size within the onCreate of the main activity. But I want to know why wont the above line in the manifest make any change to the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are viewing the app on Tablet and willing to get the small screen size view, you may also need to add this attributes :

```
android:xlargeScreens="false"
```